# what do you choose to point player in multiplayer game coding?

Tags: c

I'm making C or C++ texture multiplayer game (monopoly) and
to code multiplayer, defined type user 
when you change player or point player in main() or other()
you choose Number or pointer?
for example, when one turn finish how do you change player 
like user++ (user is int) or use changeUser() ...
i'm newby and know nothing

Comment: Are you making a _hot seat_ multi player game, where every player plays on the same computer, on the same program, or a _networked_ multi-player game?